# Prompt for computer name run the command "SMC -stop"

Tags: vbscript

So let me start by saying I am USELESS at scripting so please bear with me.

We use Symantec Endpoint Protection (SEP) across out enterprise and there seems to be an issue with Citrix XenServer 5.5 and SEP 11 where without warning SEP will stop almost all access to VM's. Generally there File and Print or Print Server VM's so either all printing at a site will stop or all file access.

When it happens you can ping a VM (so Nagios thinks its ok) and many other checks such as SNMP polling etc still work (So HP SIM thinks it ok) but RDP access and login by any Domain User is denied so you have to use XenCenter and login with a local account. Once logged on all you need to do is run 'SMC -stop' and then 'SMC -start' to stop and start all related SEP services.

Now we have a 24/7 staffed Service Desk but they are not allowed access to XenCenter so the calls get passed straight to 3rd level support and at 2am in the morning you really don't want to get woken up for something this simple.

Because you can still run commands remotely I figure some form of Script (any language) that simply prompts for a computer name and once entered runs '***SMC -Stop***', *Pauses for 15 seconds*, and then runs '***SMC -start***' and Echo's "Symantec Endpoint Protection Services Restarted" would be perfect and allow me and my team mates to get a full night sleep every now and then.

So far from butchering others scripts I have come up with the below but have not had a chance to test it yet so not even sure if it will work correctly (I did say I was bad at scripting)

```
strComputer = InputBox("Name of computer to stop SEP Services on:", "Run SMC -stop")

If strComputer = "" Then
    Wscript.Quit
End If

Dim oShell
Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")
oShell.run "cmd.exe /c SMC -Stop"

MsgBox "Waiting 15 Seconds before restarting SEP Services"
WScript.Sleep 15000

Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")
oShell.run "cmd.exe /c SMC -Start"
Set oShell = Nothing

MsgBox "Symantec Endpoint Protection Services Restarted"*
```

Apreceate any help given.

Answer (score 0):

Your script will run the command on the local computer, not on the remote computer. For executing a command on remote computers via VBScript try [WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394372):

```
computer = "..."

Sub RunRemoteCommand(cmd, host)
  Set wmi = GetObject("winmgmts://" & host & "/root/cimv2")
  rc = wmi.Get("Win32_Process").Create(cmd, , , pid)
  If rc <> 0 Then
    WScript.Echo "Running '" & cmd & "' on " & computer & " failed (" & rc & ")."
    WScript.Quit 1
  End If
End Sub

RunRemoteCommand "smc -stop", computer
WScript.Sleep 15000
RunRemoteCommand "smc -start", computer
```

You can prompt for a computer name by using the [`InputBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3yfdhzk5%28v=vs.84%29) function:

```
computer = InputBox("Enter computername:")
```

It might be simpler to run a batch script via [`PsExec`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) instead, though:

```
C:\>psexec \\computer -c restart_sep.cmd
```

with `restart_sep.cmd` looking like this:

```
@echo off
smc -stop
ping -n 16 127.0.0.1 >nul
smc -start
```

The option `-c` tells `PsExec` to copy the batch file from your local host to the remote computer before executing it there. `ping -n 16 127.0.0.1` emulates a `sleep 15` (`ping` puts ~1 second delay between 2 echo requests).